# recurring condition blocks SQL

Tags: sql, loops, if-statement, for-loop

> I want to create a recurring IF ELSE or FOR LOOP condition blocks as per below conditions
>
> I have a "created Date" column in a Data Table

I want to implement below condition

```
0-5 days from created date  
print text1  
6-10 from created date   
print text2  
11-15   
print text3  
16-20   
print text4  
21-25  
print text1  
26-30  
print text2
```

> and so on..
> so after 20 days 1st text gets gets printed again and like that for 4 set of text after every 5 days.

Comment: specify your sample table data and expected result

Comment: so, what is the end date ? if it's 1-30 you can use case statement in select query .

Comment: Show us the code. Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: @King_Fisher there is no end date. It can be continuous. 
So it always checks created date and 20 day cycle continues iteratively.
4 set of images that change every 5 days and get reset after 20 days to again show 4 set of images every 5 days and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use CASE WHEN

```
SELECT name, total, 
CASE  
 WHEN datediff(day, createdDate, getdate()) <5 THEN 'Almost Due'
 WHEN datediff(day, createdDate, getdate()) BETWEEN 6 AND 10  THEN 'Due Now'
   ...
 WHEN datediff(day, createdDate, getdate()) >20 THEN 'PAY NOW!!'
END as discount from invoice
```

or in you complex issue

```
SELECT name, total, 
CASE  (datediff(day, createdDate, getdate()) % 25)
 WHEN  <5 THEN 'Almost Due'
 WHEN  BETWEEN 6 AND 10  THEN 'Due Now'
   ...
 WHEN  >20 THEN 'PAY NOW!!'
END as discount from invoice
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of integer division and modulo, the exact operators depend upon your dialect of SQL. The following is T-SQL, MySQL would use `DIV` instead of `\`:

```
CASE (DATEDIFF(DAY, CreatedDate, GetDate()) \ 5) % 4
  WHEN 0 THEN 'text1'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'text2'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'text3'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'text4' END
```